# JS FullCalendar Day & Event Double Click Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have seen several solutions for handling these actions but the majority deal with versions older than V4.

I would like to add functions that handle double clicking on a day, and double clicking on an event.

Below is my current setup **without** the sections handling these events.

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/core/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/moment/main.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var time = new Date();
    var now = time.getHours()+":00:00";
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['dayGrid','timeGrid','interaction'],

            height: 550,
            header:{
                left:   'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today dayGridMonth timeGridWeek timeGridDay prev,next'
            },
            minTime: '05:00:00',
            maxTime: '22:00:00',
            nowIndicator: true,
            scrollTime: now,
            selectable: true,
            events: myEvents,
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            views:{
                dayGrid:{eventLimit:4},
            },
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
</script>
```

Now there are several solutions I have tried, First was below which returned an error that "fullCalendar is not a function"

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
         alert('double click!');
      });
   }
})
```

Next was below which was non-functional:

```
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
             $(element).on({
                 click: function() {
                     // Handle click...
                 },
                 dblclick: function() {
                     // Handle double click...
                 }
             });
        },
```

I believe my issues may stem from version differences. I would appreciate links to examples or other solutions dealing with this functionality in V4.

**EDIT 1** so I can currently cause alerts for clicking/double-clicking a day or event using whats below. For some reason the `dayRender` functions are only triggered when the lower half of the day is clicked. I would like assistance with this.

```
        eventRender: function(info) {
          info.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                clickCount++;
            if (clickCount === 1) {
                singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    clickCount = 0;
                    alert('single click');
                }, 400);
            } else if (clickCount === 2) {
                clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
                clickCount = 0;
                alert('double click');
            }          
          });
        },

        dayRender: function(info) {
            console.log(info.el);
          info.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount === 1) {
                singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    clickCount = 0;
                    alert('single click');
                }, 400);
            } else if (clickCount === 2) {
                clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
                clickCount = 0;
                alert('double click');
            }          
          });
        },
```

Comment: Instead of relying purely on examples and guesswork, why not read the documentation? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender . It tells you exactly what information is provided to you in the callback, and in what format. In v4 there is one single parameter provided called `info` (instead of having event and element as separate parameters). The `info` object has the element within it. Once you locate that element object (as per Dario's answer below), you can attach event handlers to it in the normal way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventRender function receives an info parameter, that contains event and element objects.
You need to use something like:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    info.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('click')
    });
}
```

See this jsfiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/6jc7ngLo/

Comment: Correct use of `info.el`...but OP wants to **double**-click. Single clicking is already handled by fullCalendar (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick), so it wouldn't be necessary to add a separate handler for that. If you update it to show how to add a double-click handler then you get my upvote :-)

Comment: Javascript has a dblclick event handler, just add the handler for that. If OP needs to handle both, there are lot of easy methods to use the single click event to detect doubleclicks.  Anyway, here is an ugly implementation for both : https://jsfiddle.net/u5gecpwr/

Comment: I'm not the OP, why are you telling me? The point of my comment was to get you to update your answer with a better example :-)

Comment: how would I change this to add listeners to each day as well? Also, is it possible to do something similar with a right click?

Comment: I attempted altering the above to `dayRender` but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: I have gotten some days to show the alerts, however it seems to only work on the lower portion of the day